# How can I attach some data for jQuery event for bubbling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The easiest way to show what I'm trying to achieve is to make a simple example:

```js
$("#button-1").click(function (e) { e.data = { flag: true } });
$("#button-2").click(function (e) { e.data = { flag: false } });

$(window).click(function (e) { $("p").html(JSON.stringify(e.data)) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='button-1'>button 1</button>
<button id='button-2'>button 2</button>

<p></p>
```

When I attach anything to an event, it gets disappeared after bubbling up to the window. Is there any way to keep it?

Comment: Why not just do `data={flag:true}` - why must it be added to the event? Or even `$("p").data("flag",true)` - then later `$("p").html($("p").data("flag"))`

Comment: Check your snippet. I don't think it's doing what you're trying to convey.

Comment: @Niche It does not, that's why I'm asking for a help

Comment: @mplungjan Because the problem I work on is much more complicated than the snippet

Comment: Then store it in a scoped variable you make yourself. It does not make sense to abuse the event - at least not given the little information you have given

Comment: @mplungjan All I need is that the element higher in DOM gets the information from children after they've processed the event. They are not two elements - there are hundreds of them and if I had a variable for them all that would be too messy. I would have to find a workaround (with variables or anything else) and I can do it myself, but what I'm asking the community about - is whether there is an ability to bind some data to an event dynamically or not. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you right now why it won't work that way, I need to first check the source of jQuery.

But you could attach it to the [`originalEvent`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). But I would probably use a more specific name then `data`, to avoid naming conflicts.

```js
$("#button-1").click(function (e) { e.originalEvent.data = { flag: true } });
$("#button-2").click(function (e) { e.originalEvent.data = { flag: false } });

$(window).click(function (e) { $("p").html(JSON.stringify(e.originalEvent.data)) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='button-1'>button 1</button>
<button id='button-2'>button 2</button>

<p></p>
```

Comment: I thought I tried this before, but must have done something wrong - it works indeed! Thank you

Comment: @andkorsh the `originalEvent` is the actual event that was emitted. The `e` you get is a wrapper that is created to have an event object that is the same in all browsers. And I assum that jQuery creates a new wrapper for each element where the even handlers are attached. So `e` is most likely the same for all event handlers of the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just attach the event to a parent with a bit of logic to handle the data based on which `target` triggered the event? See oversimplified snippet below (probably not necessary to go all the way up to `window` but this should give you the idea).

```js
$(window).click(function (event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'button-1') {
    event.data = { flag: true };
  } else if (event.target.id == 'button-2') {
    event.data = { flag: false };
  }
  
  $('p').html(JSON.stringify(event.data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button-1'>button 1</button>
<button id='button-2'>button 2</button>
<p></p>
```